# What do the different colored damage numbers represent?

Tags: star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes

I've noticed different colored numbers appearing during combat. There appears to be green, red, blue, yellow, and white numbers. Green seems to clearly represent healing instead of damage.

What does red, blue, yellow, and white numbers represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have guessed, green numbers are healing.

Red numbers are standard damage.

Yellow numbers are the damage dealt when your character scores a critical hit.

White numbers I initially thought to be ability- or status-based damage, but after some more testing I believe it may be non-critical damage that ignores armour, such as statuses or abilities that specifically take a percentage of health, or Darth Sidious' Deathstroke ability (but only some of the time as it has a 25% chance to ignore armour).

Blue numbers are special damage (but not critical special damage, critical special damage is yellow). Special damage is dealt by attacks that specifically say they deal special damage, such as Talia's Harrowing Assault, or the Jedi Consular's Attack as Defense.

Comment: This lines up with what I've noticed. Is there a reference you are referring to or is this just what you've noticed from playing?

Comment: This is just from my own testing. I can say without a doubt that green, red, yellow, and blue are correct. I'm only about 80% sure for white, though.

Comment: With white, I've noticed that it seems to be if you have to sacrifice hp for some reason. Savage Opress and support droids in challenges do a lot of white damage to themselves. I was thinking it was when it is static or non-variable damage.

Comment: To be clear, by "non-variable", I mean damage that isn't determined by a random number generator. If something does 20% of max hp or 100% of current hp or 99999 damage, then it appears to be white damage.

Comment: Yeah, that was my original assumption, but seeing Darth Sidious do white damage only sometimes, on a power that specifically says it ignores armour 25% of the time, brought me to the conclusion that is on damage that bypasses armour, as any set percentage damage would also ignore armour.

Comment: I've spent some more time paying attention to things like this. Attacks that have innate armor penetration do seem to light up as white damage. Even the upgraded Consular attack "Attack as Defense", which is normally a blue attack, will light up white 25% of the time once you've upgraded it to level 5.

Comment: I've noticed that the white number appears sometimes even when a yellow one has. It's almost as though it's not signifying damage but some other type of drain. Maybe turn meter?

Comment: @Mooz Do you know which specific characters and powers are doing this? My half-a-guess right now is that it may be something like Mace Windu's Shatterpoint, and he may be dealing 20% health (white) plus normal attack (yellow or red). Still only a theory though, until you can provide a bit more detail as to where you are seeing it.

Comment: Another thing to check - does the character you are seeing this on have an ongoing damage effect?

Comment: @winterblood 1. It was Jedi Consular. 2. It's intermittent (not every time he attacks) 3. Pretty sure it's with his attack as defence move only. I think Qui Gonn also had the same effect with one of his special attacks. I will keep my eyes peeled for a pattern :)

Comment: It seems to be almost always when I attack Savage Opress (especially in the ACI Gear Challenge). the white number is usually -10237 when I attack him and 10237 when it's his turn. I definitely see the normal red, yellow or blue redutcion in his health, but at the same time I see the white -10237 as well. I think it's got something to do with him gaining armour or turn meter or some sort of special thing like that.

Comment: @Mooz Yeah, I had seen that as well last time I played. It is just one of the effects he is suffering. I can't remember what it is called (it has a stupidly long name), but it basically means he is taking a heap of extra damage that ignores armour, thus the white colour.

Answer (score 2):

White Damage is unmitigated damage. This means it cannot be resisted/evaded and is unable to crit.

All White Damage attacks ignore armour by default. Some White attacks ignore armour/protection, but not all white attacks ignore protection, only armour.

Examples of effects/attacks that deal unmitigated damage:

- Deathmarked Characters take damage equal to 50% of the character's total health as unmitigated damage from all attacks in addition to regular damage.
- Damage over Time deals 5% of a character's total HP as unmitigated damage.
- Darth Nihilus's Annihilate ability does unmitigated damage to raid bosses (99,999 damage).
- Savage Opress's overpower ability does 99,999 unmitigated damage against enemies with less than 25% health (50% with Omega).
- Slave 1's Seismic Charge attack deals direct damage to Health, ignoring Armour/Protection, as well as taking 20/30% of the target's total health.
- The AAT's main cannon deals 99,999 unmitigated damage to characters without a buff.
- The Phase 4 Firestorm attack in Heroic AAT deal 99,999 unmitigated damage to all un-buffed characters.